# Simple form: bind collection select choices to a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a model with a boolean attribute "public". 
In a simple form, on the edit interface, I have this:

```
  <%= f.input :public, :collection => ['Public', 'Private'],  label: "Access", selected: 1 %>
```

I don't want to have `true` or `false` in the options of the select, but I need to bind `Public` to `true` and `Private` to `false`, so when the form is submitted it saves the public attribute to `true` or `false`.

I could tweak things in the controller but I'd like to know if there is a clean way to do this.

Also, since it's the edit page, the public attribute already has a value. How can I, here too, bind the value stored either to `Public` or `Private` in order to have the currently saved value displayed in the form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= f.input :public, 
        :as => :select, 
        :collection => [['Private',false],['Public',true]], 
        :include_blank => false, 
        :selected => false,
        :label => "Public?" %>
```